# Mailgun sending email laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, email

i use mailgun and the setting is done and i've test it and work, but i dont understand why i can't send email without array, here i tried using array but idk why it's error said Undefined variable: data

```
public function kirim(Request $request){

    $data = array(
        'email_address'=>$request->email_address,
        'cc'=>$request->cc,
        'subject'=>$request->subject,
        'keterangantambahan'=>$request->keterangantambahan
    );

    Mail::send('laporan.kirim', $data, function($message) {
        $message->from('christian7andrew@gmail.com', 'PuraBox');
        $message->to($data['email_address']);
    });

    return redirect('/');
}
```

any idea how to use array corectly ??

Comment: which version of laravel are you using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `use`.

Looks like you are using a php version which supports [closures](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
Mail::send('laporan.kirim', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
    $message->from('christian7andrew@gmail.com', 'PuraBox');
    $message->to($data['email_address']);
});
```

The second parameter of the `send()` method is to set *mail options*. Does not place the variable inside the function body.

The `use` puts variables into the body of the function